# Splitting a time range into hours?

Tags: php, algorithm, datetime, time

I'm currently working with a data set containing a start time, date, and a duration in seconds, and need to be able to split the range of times from start time to (start time + duration, e.g. end time) into hour "buckets" if you will.

So for instance, a start time of 08:30:00 with duration 9000 seconds (2.5 hours) covers hour 08 from 8:30:00 to 09:00:00 for 1800 seconds, hour 09 until 10:00:00 for 3600 seconds, etc. up to the end time of 11:00:00.

What would be the best way possible to do this? I'm working in PHP however a general algorithmic solution would still be incredibly helpful.

My current approach is as follows:

```
1. Calculate the hour difference between both times (round up to next hour if there's a non-zero number of minutes)
2. Let session progress = 0
3. Iterate the range from 1 to hour difference:
    1. Let the current bucket duration = min(3600, duration)
    2. Let the duration = max(0, duration - current bucket duration)
    3. Let bucket start time = start time + session progress
    4. Let bucket end time = bucket start time + current bucket duration
    5. Do work based on these values
    6. Let session progress += current bucket duration
```

My PHP implementation of this is as follows:

```
foreach ($csv as $listen_record) {
    $start_dt = $listen_record['Date'] . ' ' . $listen_record['Time'];
    $session_duration = $listen_record['Duration'];

    $session_start_time = date_create_from_format($datetime_format, $start_dt);

    $session_end_time = clone $session_start_time;
    date_add($session_end_time, date_interval_create_from_date_string($session_duration . ' seconds'));

    $diff = date_diff($session_end_time, $session_start_time);
    $hourdiff = $diff->h;

    if ($diff->m > 0)
        $hourdiff += 1;

    $session_progress = 0;

    foreach (range(1, $hourdiff) as $hour) {
        $record_duration = min(3600, $session_duration);
        $session_duration = max(0, $session_duration - $record_duration);

        $record_start_time = clone $session_start_time;
        date_add($record_start_time, date_interval_create_from_date_string($session_progress . ' seconds'));

        $record_end_time = clone $record_start_time;
        date_add($record_end_time, date_interval_create_from_date_string($record_duration . ' seconds'));

        if ($record_start_time == $record_end_time)
            continue;

        // DO WORK...

        $session_progress += $record_duration;
    }
}
```

This kind of works to separate each record into hour long buckets however gives some weird results for some cases (particularly cases where the range crosses into a new day) and doesn't align to actual wall clock hours.

Is there a better way to do this that can actually align to wall clock hours and not freak out when it has to cope with durations that cross over midnight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: I managed to solve this on my own so I'm posting how I did it just in case anyone else needs to do similar.**

Basically I did it by creating a range between the start and end timestamp, and filtering out every time stamp apart from start and end that isnt a multiple of 3600 or just before 3600. This gives me the wall clock hours in the middle of the range as timestamps. I can then split the array into chunks of 2 which contains the slot start time and end time.

My PHP code is as follows and now actually works:

```
function is_wall_clock_aligned_hour_boundary($timestamp) {
    return ($timestamp % (60*60) === 0) || (($timestamp + 1) % (60*60) === 0);
}

function create_slot_object($slot) {
    $start_time = reset($slot);
    $end_time = end($slot);
    $duration = $end_time - $start_time;

    return array(
        'startTime' => convert_timestamp_to_datetime($start_time),
        'endTime' => convert_timestamp_to_datetime($end_time),
        'duration' => $duration
    );
}

function make_slots(DateTime $start_time, $duration) {
    $start_timestamp = $start_time->getTimestamp();

    $end_time = clone $start_time;
    date_add($end_time, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$duration seconds"));

    $end_timestamp = $end_time->getTimestamp();

    $time_sequence = range($start_timestamp, $end_timestamp);
    $slot_boundaries = array_filter($time_sequence, 'is_wall_clock_aligned_hour_boundary');

    array_unshift($slot_boundaries, $start_timestamp);
    array_push($slot_boundaries, $end_timestamp);

    $slots = array_chunk($slot_boundaries, 2);

    return array_map('create_slot_object', $slots);
}
```